# Error While using the CopyFile function

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

Hello I am using the `CopyFile` function in Delphi 5. But the file is not getting copied to destination. I am not able to see error also. What is the best way to know why `CopyFile` is failing?

```
if CopyFile(source, dest, false) then
  ShowMessage('Success')
else
  ShowMessage('Error');
```

I am getting displayed error always. :(

Comment: You should be using pchar (CopyFile(pchar(sourcefile), pchar(destfile), false).  To check if file copies, use FileExists(destfile).. You can wrap your CopyFile in a try/except and respond to the exception...

Comment: @JohnEasley That's all true, but doesn't help to identify the error code.

Comment: Primary failure modes: 1. Source does not exist 2. Dest path does not exist 3. Dest file read only 4. Permissions error.

Comment: For example, trying to replace a file which is currently opened (thus locked)

Comment: @JohnEasley: The cast to `PChar` isn't necessary in most cases (like what appears to be shown here). It typically only applies when Delphi can't automatically do the conversion, like when you combine a variable and a constant (eg., `SourcePath + 'SomeFile.txt'`).

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you. The CopyFile parameters (in d2010) are PWideChar. Is it bad programming practice to match parameter types?

Comment: @JohnEasley: This question was about D5/7 (pre-Unicode), where the parameters are `PChar` (same as `PAnsiChar`), and `CopyFile` is actually `CopyFileA` under the hood. Doesn't matter, though - in D2010, `string` is Unicode, and Delphi will still auto-convert when possible without the typecast, same as above; in D2010, `CopyFile` is actually `CopyFileW` for the wide string version. The auto-conversion Delphi does is similar to the way it allows you to drop the `^` operator when accessing class instances (which are pointers) or records like `TPoint`, so you can use `Form1.` instead of `Form1^.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the function fails you can  get extended error information, calling the  [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  method or use the RaiseLastOSError method.

Check this sample

```
  try
    If copyFile(source , dest,false) then
     ShowMessage('Success')
    else
     RaiseLastOSError;
  except  on E: Exception do
     showMessage(Format('Error executing copyFile %s',[E.Message]));
  end;
```

Comment: getting error undeclared identiier:RaiseLastOSError. :( in which unit its included?

Comment: sorry i was using delphi 5. :( by mistake i wrote 7.

Comment: now getting message Win32 API unction getting failed. any idea why its failed?

Comment: @Naren in Delphi 5 you can use the `RaiseLastWin32Error` method.

Comment: yes i used that only and getting message 'Win32 API unction getting failed'

Comment: What's the real error message? Please don't make up error messages.